# How to get the table over which a view has been made in AWS Athena?

Tags: boto3, amazon-athena, presto

Is there any way to get the table over which a view has been made in AWS Athena. I know in the console we can use `Show/edit query` option to get the query for view creation, but is there any programmatic way to do it or any boto3 support for this ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  When you create a view in athena a table is created in Glue Catalog.  You need to get the details of that catalog table (named for the view) and the query that was used to create the view along with the original table name are in the result.

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client("glue")
response = client.get_table(DatabaseName='your_database', Name='your_view')
print(response["Table"]["ViewOriginalText"])
```

You'll get back a response string that looks like this:

```
"/* Presto View: eyJvcmlnaW5hbFNxbCI6I...[snip]...VnZXIifV19 */"
```

The middle part is a base64 encoded string of your query creation string.

Comment: I don't understand when you say a table is created in Glue Catalog when we create a view ? Also I would like to get the original table over which the view has been made. I am sorry if the earlier title of the question misguided you in any manner.

Comment: When you create a View in Athena, a new table with the same name is created in glue catalog.  Yes, I understood you wanted the original table, if you run the code I put above against the view/table that's in the catalog, you'll get the query for the original table the view is based on.

Comment: I don't find it a clean way but I don't suppose we have any other way round.